# changing text in parent UserControl from Child UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

If a `ParentUserControl` contains a `TextBlock`. The `ParentUserControl`also contains `ChildUserControl` that has a `TextBox`. I want to set the `TextBlock` of `ParentUserControl` value from `ChildTextBox`. how can i ?
In other words somehow accessing the `ParentUserControl` and it's `TextBlock` element and then modifying it's value from `ChildUserControl` !

**Update**
i have a xaml window that contains a `ParentUserControl` that has a `TextBlock`. Now i am loading or adding another `ChildUserControl` into it on runtime. This newly added `ChildUserControl` contains a `ChildTextBox`. Now i want that when i input some value into this `ChildTexBox` the `ParentUserControl`'s `TextBlock` should get that value and update itself.

Comment: There are numerous ways to achieve this. I am trying to update answer for you in short.

Comment: @GK please tell me simplest back end solution :( struggling for a while now to solve this :( :(

Comment: On the way, just 5 more mins :)

Comment: just noticed the wpf tag. ignore me. lol

Comment: @GK but it says ! can not access non static `ChildTextBox` in a static context !!!

Comment: You've already asked this today and got a perfect answer. I've voted for [undeleting that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838422/modify-textblock-value-of-parent-usercontrol-from-child-usercontrol-wpf?noredirect=1#comment92593071_52838422). The answer there is the only approach that makes sense. You'll have to understand what was suggested in the answer, otherwise you should give up on WPF.

Comment: @hammas_Stack can you post the xaml and code-behind of what you have tried so far? I guess there is something else you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are not following any MVVM and a simple approach for this problem is,

1. Create a ChildUserControl with a textbox inside it as below,

   ```
         <UserControl x:Class="SO52840402.ChildUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO52607887"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
     <Grid>
      <TextBox x:Name="ChildTextBox" />
     </Grid>  </UserControl>
   ```
2. Create a ParentUserControl which contains a TextBlock and ChildUserControl instance as shown below,

   ```
          <UserControl x:Class="SO52840402.ParentUserControl"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO52607887"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
   <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition />
         <RowDefinition />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <TextBlock x:Name="ParentTextBlock" Text="Hallo World!"/>

     <local:ChildUserControl x:Name="ChildUserControl" Grid.Row="1" />

   </Grid>  </UserControl>
   ```
3. Now create a TextChanged event for the TextBox which is under ChildUserControl from code behind of ParentUserControl constructor after "InitializeComponent" as shown below,

   ```
   public ParentUserControl()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       ChildUserControl.ChildTextBox.TextChanged += OnChildTextBox_TextChanged;
   }

   private void OnChildTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ParentTextBlock.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
   }
   ```

Note:- This is a not a recommended approach. For best approach, follow MVVM pattern and understand your requirements and do the design. Since you need something from a child user control from a parent user control, a best approach is to have a ViewModel bind to parent and child and access child view model in parent viewmodel and do "what ever you want".

Comment: @hammas_Stack Post your code in an update to the question. You're doing something off.

Comment: @Marisa my code is more complex. i mean idk how to get a part of it and share here . but the problem is same which i have asked !

Comment: Why the answer was down voted? Is that the reason that you are getting some other error? I would be able to clarify myself or change my answer or correct myself if I know the reason.

In case if the down vote is for the error what @hammas_Stack has mentioned, then I would request to post the code to understand and give more suggestions.

Comment: @hammas_Stack The best practice when asking for help is to replicate the code in an independent project. If you can't, you don't understand your code or the problem well enough for us to help. If it doesn't occur, then it's something specific to your environment. If it does, you have a testable scenario we can assist with.